# Apache beam PubSubIO write

Tags: java, java-8, apache-beam

Unable to write to PubSub using Apache Beam JavaSDK.

I am trying to use beam to read from PubSub, do processing and then write the data to a PubSub topic, but i am unable to find working example on how to write to a PubSub.

Can someone help with the appropriate transformation to write to PubSub Topic.

```
.apply("Create pubsub messages", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, PubsubMessage>() {
    @DoFn.ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = new PubsubMessage(c.element());
        c.output(pubsubMessage);
    }
  }))
.apply("Write messages to topic",PubsubIO.writeMessages().to("projects/project_id/topics/topic_name"))
```

I am currently getting compilation error

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/username/src/main/java/com/domain/JavaClass.java:[336,1] no suitable method found for apply(java.lang.String,org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo.SingleOutput<java.lang.String,org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage>)
    method org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<OutputT>apply(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform<? super org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>,OutputT>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) OutputT
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<OutputT>apply(java.lang.String,org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform<? super org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>,OutputT>) is not applicable
      (inference variable InputT has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: java.lang.String
        lower bounds: org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>)
[ERROR] /home/username//src/main/java/com/domain/JavaClass.java:[339,39] constructor PubsubMessage in class org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage cannot be applied to given types;
  required: byte[],java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what is not working for you with the code snippet you included.

Comment: Can you post the part of the pipeline before this sinpet, ie what PCollection are you feeding into the "Create pubsub messages" transformation. The snipet itself looks ok and I use something very similar and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of read from GCS and write on pub/sub:

```
package ...

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

public class Gcs2PubSub {

    public interface Pubsub2DatastoreOptions extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
        @Description("GCP project name")
        @Default.String("gcp_project_name")
        String getProjectId();
        void setProjectId(String value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Pubsub2DatastoreOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(Pubsub2DatastoreOptions.class);

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        PCollection<String> line = p.apply("Read GCS",TextIO.read().from("gs://<bucket>/*"));
        line.apply("Sending Pub/sub",PubsubIO.writeStrings().to("<topic>"));

        PipelineResult result = p.run();
        try {
            result.waitUntilFinish();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            result.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```